# How to stick the container to the bottom of the screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this registration form setup within a container, I want this container to stick to the bottom of the screen. I tried wrapping it with the Positioned widget and setting its bottom to zero, but it does not work.

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: kSpacingUnit * 1.0),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: kBoxShadow,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          0.1 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
          0.1 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
          0.1 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
          0.00 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
        ),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 0.1 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.00 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.00 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Email Address cannot be left empty';
                      }
                      if (!value.contains('@') || !value.contains('.')) {
                        return 'Enter a valid Email Address';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() => _email = value.trim());
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
                      labelText: 'Email Address',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        color: Colors.black54,
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                    onTap: null,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.00 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.00 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Password cannot be left empty';
                      }
                      if (value.length < 6) {
                        return 'Password needs to be at least 6 characters long';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() => _password = value);
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline),
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        color: Colors.black54,
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.remove_red_eye,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.00 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Forgot Password ?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 0.05 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      final _signInResponse =
                          _auth.signInWithEmail(this._email, this._password);
                      if (_signInResponse != null) {
                        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
                       }
                    }
                  },
                  child: LoginButton(
                    buttonTitle: 'Sign In',
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    iconPath: Icons.lock_outline,
                    iconColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 0.02 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.00 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                    0.05 * SizingInfo.screenWidth,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Need an account?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                             context, '/signup'),
                        child: Text(
                          'Sign Up',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFF528DF9),
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 0.05 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 0.01 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Divider(
                            height: 0.0,
                            thickness: 0.5,
                            color: Colors.black54,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '   Sign In With   ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Divider(
                            height: 0.0,
                            thickness: 0.5,
                            color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 0.075 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircleButton(
                      onTap: () => print("Google"),
                      imagePath: 'assets/images/google.png',
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 0.1 * SizingInfo.screenWidth),
                    CircleButton(
                      onTap: () => print("Facebook"),
                      imagePath: 'assets/images/facebook.png',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit * 5.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

This is how the screen looks:

[image]

Could anyone please help with fixing this issue. Thank you so much in advance!

UPDATE:

After applying the solution suggested by @Besufkd, the container has stuck to the bottom but some unwanted white space is appearing below the Google and Facebook buttons as shown in the below screens, could you please help me with fixing this issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: so you don't require a bottom blue container, instead, it should show Fb and google icons below.

Comment: The blue is the background of the Scaffold.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Answer (score 4):

check this

```
  Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [Expanded(
          child: Container(),
        ),
        // this will be you container
        Container()
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks @Besufkad the container has got sticked to bottom, but there is lot of space below the FB and Google buttons. I want to get rid of that space.

Comment: `SizedBox(height: kSpacingUnit * 5.0),` remove this part then from the bottom

Comment: Thanks @Besufkad I have removed it and attached the updated screen, still the white space exists.

Comment: add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end` in the column inside SingleChildScrollView

Comment: Sorry @Besufkad, it didn't help. I'm not sure from which widget that white space is getting rendered.

Answer (score 2):

new Expanded(

```
        child: new Align(

            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,

            child: Container(

              height: 50,

              width: 100,

              color: Colors.blue,

              child: new Column(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,

                children: <Widget>[

                  new Text("Hello")

                ],
              ),

            )))
```